# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'find'

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

My javascript code runs fine in Chrome, however if I keep 'Developer Tools' open I get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'find'

and the javascript code stops working.

Here is the [page](http://meracd.com/design/disc_designer.php).

It is a Chrome specific problem.

Comment: Am not getting the error with Chrome v19.0.1084.56...

Comment: Could you post the relative code?

Comment: @vellvisher even i'm using ver 19.0.1084.56 m, try keeping your dev tools (ctrl+shift+i) open before loading the site.

Comment: @xdazz :) I wasted 2 hrs trying to get rid of the problem before I finally stumbled on to the solution. this is the main js file -http://bit.ly/M8gI98 and chrome shows error in jQuery 1.7.1

Comment: @user461844 I don't get any error with chrome.

Comment: here is a screenshot of the error - http://img225.imageshack.us/img225/9576/chromeerror.png
I tried disabling the extensions, despite that I get the error.

Comment: I can confirm the error and it only shows when the dev tools are open on page load which is strange. Normally all errors are logged even without dev tools and show up when you open the console.

Comment: @Thomas I see lots of uncaught type error: Object # type errors specific to chrome, is it a chrome issue as opposed to being a coding error?

Comment: I don't know but I get a slightly different error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'find'` Maybe that (HTMLLIElement) will help to track it down.

Comment: I have the same issue in Chrome. I think it is related to $.tabs(). Did someone come up with a solution or why is it happening?

Comment: in fact, there is an entire family of related errors

Comment: @YoniBaciu I am having bascially the same issue. See my Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11318224/561731