# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'find' in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, tinymce, jquery-ui-tabs

Might be related to : [Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'find'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11134646/561731)

---

Here is a chat of the discussion of my problem:    https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/conversation/tabs-issue
It continues through here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4373231#4373231

---

I am doing the following:

```
$(document).on({
"click": function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".TaskRow").not(this).removeClass("active").removeClass("hoverActive");
    $(".TaskDetails").hide();
    $(document).off("keyup", "body", keyDownFn);
    keyDownFn = makeRelationships(this);
    $(document).on("keyup", "body", keyDownFn);
    var thisTaskDetails = ".task" + $(this).data("id") + "Details";
    if (detailsArray[thisTaskDetails] !== undefined) {
        detailsArray[thisTaskDetails].show();
        var td = $(".taskDetails", detailsArray[thisTaskDetails]);
        if ($(".hide", detailsArray[thisTaskDetails]).length) {
            toggleMCE(td, $(".taskCopy", detailsArray[thisTaskDetails]))
            $("#" + td.attr("id") + "_parent", detailsArray[thisTaskDetails]).show();
        }
    } else {
        var thisID = $(this).data("id"),
            displayTask = function () {
                $.get(WEBROOT + INDEX + "/Task/displayTask/" + thisID, function (data) {
                    var domElement = $(data),
                        saveThis = function () {
                            $("form", domElement).trigger("submit");
                            return true;
                        },
                        taskDetails = $(".taskDetailsArea", domElement);

                    console.log(domElement);
                    detailsArray[thisTaskDetails] = domElement.appendTo(bottomLeftPane);
                    detailsArray[thisTaskDetails].tabs();  //ERROR HERE
                    console.log(domElement, detailsArray);
                    //*
                    taskDetails.tinymce({
                        // Location of TinyMCE script
                        script_url: INDEX + '/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                        // General options
                        theme: "advanced",
                        plugins: "autolink,lists,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,advlist",

                        // Theme options
                        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                        theme_advanced_buttons2: "pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
                        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
                        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

                        //Saving:
                        save_enablewhendirty: true,
                        save_onsavecallback: saveThis,

                        //                                    width: $("#leftPane").width(), height: $("#leftPane").height(),

                        //Setup:
                        setup: function (ed) {
                            console.log(ed, "setup");
                            ed.onChange.add(function (ed) { //blur
                                console.log('Editor was changed: ' + ed.id);
                                saveThis();
                                //                                          toggleMCE(taskDetails, $(".taskCopy", domElement));
                            });
                            ed.onClick.add(function (ed, evt) { //focus
                                console.log('Editor was clicked: ' + ed.id, evt);
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    $("form", domElement).on("submit", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var posts = $(this).serialize();
                        $.post(WEBROOT + INDEX + "/Task/changeSomething", posts);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $("form", domElement).on("focus", function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        console.log("focused on body", e);
                        return false;
                    });
                    //*/
                });
            };

        if (thisID !== undefined) {
            displayTask();
        } else {

        }
    }
}
}, ".TaskRow");
```

This whole error only happens on **second** load of this function. And it fails by the line `detailsArray[thisTaskDetails].tabs();`

Here is the stack trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLLIElement> has no method 'find' jquery.js:2
e.fn.e.init jquery.js:2
e jquery.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js:446
e.fn.e.map jquery.js:2
e.extend.map jquery.js:2
e.fn.e.map jquery.js:2
d.widget._tabify jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js:445
d.widget._create jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js:443
b.Widget._createWidget jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js:30
b.widget.b.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js:28
b.widget.bridge.b.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js:29
e.extend.each jquery.js:2
e.fn.e.each jquery.js:2
b.widget.bridge.b.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js:29
$.on.click.displayTask :2525/#tabs-25:502
f.Callbacks.n jquery.js:2
f.Callbacks.o.fireWith jquery.js:2
w jquery.js:4
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.send.d jquery.js:4
```

I am using `Chrome 20+`

---

##Aside:

What is returned in the `$.get` is from php:

```
<div class="TaskDetails Task task<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?>Details">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Users</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Array</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1" style="padding: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <form method="post" data-row="<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?>">
            <?php 
            $details = $task['Task']['taskDetails'];
            $details = nl2br($details);
            $details = str_replace(array("\\r\\n", "\\r"), "\n", $details);
            $details = implode("",explode("\n", $details));
            $details = stripslashes($details);
            ?>
            <textarea id="task<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?>Details" name="changedTo" class="Task task<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?> taskDetails taskDetailsArea"><?php echo $details; ?></textarea>
            <div id="task<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?>Details" class="taskCopy"><?php echo $details; ?></div>
            <input name="changed" value="taskDetails" type="hidden"/>
            <input name="row" value="<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?>" type="hidden"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2" class="Task task<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?> taskUsers">
        <?php echo $task['Task']['taskUsers']; ?>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3" class="Task task<?php echo $task['Task']['taskId']; ?>">
            <pre><?php print_r($task);?></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

##More info:
`detailsArray` is an empty object `{}` at the start.
`var thisTaskDetails = ".task" + $(this).data("id") + "Details";`
`$(this)` is some arbitrary DOM element that was clicked on.

Comment: @RobW I have tested it in Chrome 20+, I have not tested in lower versions....

Comment: Could you include code to reproduce the problem in your question? It's not going to work atm, because `detailsArray` is not declared & defined.

Comment: @RobW maybe this helps get you up to speed http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4373156#4373156 Basically jQuery is calling `this.constructor(context)` and it returns a plain DOM element which causes the error because plain dom element doesn't have `.find`

Comment: @RobW I added all of that information at the bottom.

Comment: @RobW anything else that could be helpful?

Comment: A static jfiddle (remove irrelevant lines) would be nice, because I can only find *parts* of your code in the question and chat. Surely, I can combine them and test it, but you've already got a PoC, so.. ;)

Comment: @RobW I have no idea how make a fiddle out of this... This is all a proprietary app for my office....

Comment: I've created a very stripped version, without getting the error: http://jsfiddle.net/8xmRp/. 1. Is the AJAX part necessary? 2. Are the other lines also relevant? `.addClass` won't harm anyone, I guess. But I fail to see the role of `if (... undefined)`.

Comment: @RobW it works **fine** if tinyMCE is not there.... it might be a tinyMCE issue... idk...

Comment: @RobW see my update: it works **fine** without tinyMCE: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8xmRp/1/

Comment: @RobW and it seems to be working _sort of_ fine with tinyMCE. although it too has an error on second click: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8xmRp/4/

Comment: I also notice the error. First, I reverted the order: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8xmRp/6/. I still get the error. Upon further inspection, it seems that the contents of tiny_mce.js is cut off after a certain number of characters. I cam't find another host/cdn to fix the fiddle. Including the code in the page causes new 404 errors: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8xmRp/5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may help better programmers than me zero in on a solution:

I've been noticing this error for the past week on a JS page-builder interface that I wrote myself. (No TinyMCE, but tons of jQuery plugins.) I've come to the same conclusions as the author of this ticket, i.e., jQuery is erroneously calling find() on a plain DOM element.

The interesting thing is that the problem goes away when you close the Chrome Debugger. (I'm sure we can all appreciate the irony of that one.)

I know that that doesn't bring you any closer to a solution, but at least you can rest assured that 99.9% of your users (unless they're coming  from StackOverflow I suppose) will probably never see this problem.

Comment: Hmmmm, I am going to look into this tomorrow morning and get back to you on it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in Google chrome document Inspector. There is a family of related errors. It doesn't happen in other browsers. One good thing is that most users won't find this error. On the other hand, I lost 3 hrs trying to debug the problem with document inspector, when the actual solution was to close the document inspector!

Comment: I wasted just as much time! Thank you so much. Wow.... It seems like I wasted a lot of time for no reason... :-(

Comment: You should post this as the answer to your question and mark it as accepted... .This is a silly error.... :-\

Comment: who knows, some one may come up with some elegant jquery kungfu and manage to actually solve the problem.